# Implement Microsoft Outlook Calendar on a private project

Tags: angular, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

As the title implies, I'm trying to implement Microsoft's Graph API.
So far I've implemented everything I need except for the Calendar.
My problem is that I can't seem to implement any REST methods for their calendar.

My project is built using Angular and I am stuck at where to go to implement their calendar fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by making the calendar grab events from your account session and by fixing permissions in Azure AD.

Then I made the calendar list your events and show them as dots on the calendar.

Easy fix that took way too long but it's a private project, thankfully I didn't abandon it.